# Invalidating NSTimer in a separate function than timer is in

Tags: swift

Hi If I have a NSTimer declared in one function, however wish to terminate that Timer in a different function, how should I go about doing this? I know this is a pretty novice question however when I do EnemySpawner1.invalidate in swift it dose not recognize EnemySpawner1 as it's in a different function. Any Ideas how I should go by this?

```
var EnemySpawner1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("EnemySpawner1Method"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store a reference to this timer beyond the scope of the one function (which makes sense) then you need to move the declaration of it outside that scope. Likely on some other object that makes sense to hold a reference to that timer.

> Edit

Also, remember that when you invalidate the timer it must be done on the same thread as it was created.